# Hierarchical relationship of the data with analytic function

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This question is related with my previous post, the original table as below

```
Customer_ID   Account_ID     Paying_Account_ID    Parent_Account_ID    Company_ID
 158            158             158                  158                     0
 159            159             158                  158                     0
 160            160             158                  158                     0
 181            181             181                  181                     0
 183            183             183                  183                     0
 24669          24669           24669                24669                   0         
 24671          24671           24671                24669                   0
 24670          24670           24670                24669                   0     
 3385127        3385127         3385127              24670                   0
```

To identify the hierarchical relationship of the data, which are `PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID` and `ACCOUNT_ID`, below is the query that I was used.

```
SELECT lpad(' ', 2*level) || A.ACCOUNT_ID AS LEVEL_LABEL,
       CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE "Cycle",
       LEVEL,
       A.*
FROM   ACCOUNT A
START WITH parent_account_id = account_id
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR A.ACCOUNT_ID = A.PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID AND
        account_id <> parent_account_id;
```

This is the result from the query

```
Level_Label Level CustomerID AccountID Paying_AccountID Parent_AccountID CompanyID
  158          1       158        158           158          158             0
    159        2       159        159           158          158             0
    160        2       160        160           158          158             0
  181          1       181        181           181          181             0
  183          1       183        183           183          183             0
  24669        1       24669      24669         24669        24669           0       
    24671      2       24671      24671         24671        24669           0
    24670      2       24670      24670         24670        24669           0         
     3385127   3       3385127    3385127       3385127      3385127         0
```

My question is how can I modify the query in order to calculate the values for:

- My_Total_PR - Number of my child PR accounts which does not include itself.
- Total_PR - Total number of PR accounts in the overall structure
- My_Total_NPR - Number of my child NPR accounts which does not include itself.
- Total_NPR - Total number of NPR accounts in the overall structure

*PR* stands for Payment Responsible, for instance, the payment responsible for Account 158 is 158 (`Paying_Account_ID`), so the `Total_PR` for 158 is 3 (158, 159, 160)
*NPR* stands for Non Payment Responsible, for instance the payment responsible for Account 159 is 158 (`Paying_Account_ID`), so the `Total_NPR` for 159 is 1.

This is the expected result, any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
Level_Label Level Cycle My_Total_PR Total_PR  My_Total_NPR Total_NPR Paying_Account
 158          1      0       2         3          0              0        158
   159        2      0       0         0          0              1        158
   160        2      0       0         0          0              1        158
 181          1      0       0         1          0              0        181
 183          1      0       0         1          0              0        183
 24669        1      0       0         1          3              3        24669  
   24671      2      0       0         1          0              0        24671
   24670      2      0       0         1          1              1        24670
    3385127   3      0       0         1          0              0        3385127
```

Comment: The operator between the last `account_id` and `parent_account_id` was missing. I think in previous question it was `!=`, but it did not make much sense to me. Could you please confirm what operator did you use? I inserted `=`.

Comment: account_id <> parent_account_id

Comment: Actually the account_id <> parent_account_id  can be ignored.

Comment: I don't have an Oracle instance handy so I can't work out the details, but look at Analytic Functions.

Answer (score 0):

The "total" queries have IMO no place in your query, because they are not specfic to an account. I would not try to squeeze them into your query but write separate queries for them.

However, the "my" queries are specific to an account (or customer_id ?). My general approach would be the following:

Try to write a query which aswers the particular question (e.g. *Number of my child PR accounts which does not include itself*) for a single given account. No doubt this query will contain a clause like "and account_id = 158".

Then you can do two things:

Either you remove this clause and you make sure the account_id is exposed. The query will then answer your question for *all* accounts. Then you can join this select with your hierarchical query as in

```
select ...
from 
    (treeQuery) t,
    (myQuery) m
where
    t.account_id = m.account_id;
```

Or alternativey since the "my" queries return only a single value, you can use them in the projection. as in

```
select
    (select myQuery where account_id = t.account_id) alias1,
     t.* -- or whatever columns you want to see
from
    treeQuery t;
```